# reactJS , accessing URL with daynamic segments says 'page not found'

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, react-router

The issue is pretty obvious. I have declared a route with 2 dynamic parts in my [react.js](https://reactjs.org/) app with the following line :

```
<Route  path='/products/:cat_id/:subcat_id' component={ProductsWise} />
```

But when I try to access the url: http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/4/1 , it simply says :
**404 Not Found**. The code follows :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
  import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
  import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
  import ProductsWise from './ProductsWise'
  
  class App extends Component {
    render () {
      return (
        <BrowserRouter>
          <div>
            <Header />
            <Switch>

              <Route  path='/products/:cat_id/:subcat_id' component={ProductsWise} />
              

            </Switch>
          </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
      )
    }
  }
  
  ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

I am not putting the content inside `ProductsWise.js` here as I think that is not necessary to solve the problem.

How to get rid of the problem ?

**P.S:** I am actually building an app with PHP Laravel framework in server side and react.js in client side.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React-router urls don't work when refreshing or writing manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writing-manually)

Comment: @falinsky, difficult to understand as the answer is very lengthy. But it does not deal with the dynamic segment part as in my question, right ?

Comment: the thing is that in order to make your app working your backend should render the same `index.html` for `http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/4/1` as well as for `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`

Comment: @falinsky, In `web.php` of Laravel, the default route is declared as `Route::view('/{path?}', 'app');`. So every url request loads the `app.blade.php` file. So my app satisfies your condition, I think

Comment: you can open your browser console with `http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/4/1` requested and look at the response of your web server in order to confirm that this 404 is returned by it.

Comment: @falinsky, I said in OP  that the app says ,'page not found'. Do you mean this error can from client side  instead of server side ? Browser network tab shows  the URL producing a 404 error.

Comment: so the cause of the issue that you haven't configured your backend to render the same content for `http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/4/1` as for `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222742/discussion-between-istiaque-ahmed-and-falinsky).

Comment: @falinsky, your suggestion works as discussed in chat room. Can you post it as an answer so that I can accept it  ?

Comment: My pleasure to help you =). answer posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the SPA is not rendered for the `products/4/1` path from the backend perspective.

I believe `Route::view('/{path?}', 'app')` is not relevant.

As far as there is no information about wildcard routing in the official Laravel [routing](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing) documentation - you can render your SPA for `/` and for `/products/{catId}/{subcatId}` paths separately:

```
Route::view('/', 'app');
Route::view('/products/{catId}/{subcatId}', 'app');
```

Comment: `I believe Route::view('/{path?}', 'app') is not relevant.` - then how will a URl like `cat/create` work ?

Comment: May I ask you to have a look at another react related question h ere :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64359611/reactjs-building-a-dynamic-horizontal-menu-with-dropdown-items-in-react-bootstr ?

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed `then how will a URl like cat/create work ?` - we haven't discussed this case at all. what are you talking about?